# change parent style if has a specified children in css

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have an html element that can have either a child with id='slideshow'

```
<div id='content'>
   <div id='slideshow'>
   </div>
</div>
```

or a different child

```
<div id='content'>
   <div id='other'>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a style to #content only if it has a child #slideshow.

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: [no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not (yet?) possible in CSS alone. You can however do it with a couple of lines in jquery or almost any other javascript framework.